# PDFReader renders a smaller output than expected in Android

Tags: android, pdf-reader

I was following this YouTube tutorial on [how to use PDFRenderer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YPJCOxiklQ) to display PDFs on an ImageView. I downloaded the code (link in the description) and I tried it myself. It works and it displays the PDF. However, the output I get is rather small. It does not occupy the entire imageView area.

Here is my layout life:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Previous" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout >
```

Here is my `render()` function:

```
private void render() {

    try{
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        int REQ_WIDTH = imageView.getWidth();
        int REQ_HEIGHT = imageView.getHeight();

        Log.e(TAG, "width = " + REQ_WIDTH);
        Log.e(TAG, "height  = " + REQ_HEIGHT);

        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String destination = SDCardRoot.toString() + "/my/fileHere.pdf";

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        File file = new File(destination);
        PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

        if(currentPage < 0) {
            currentPage = 0;
        } else if(currentPage > renderer.getPageCount()) {
            currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
        }

        Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT);
        renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, rect, m, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.invalidate();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "catch: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

My width is 1536 and the height is 1792. However, the output does not maximize the imageview's length and width. I had to play with the width and height values for a while. Multiplying them with an integer gave smaller outputs, while dividing gave larger outputs (albeit that the quality seems to have been compromised).

It seems that this was added in Android L so it is relatively new. However, there seems to be rather minimal tutorials regarding it - considering that we finally have a "native" PDF viewing class.